# Choosing between different types using the generic type, JAVA

Tags: java, generics

Generic types: Don't they exist to make things easier?
I wonder why I cannot do this in Java:

```
if(input.equals("Integer")) {
    GenericClass<Integer> mygen = new GenericClass<Integer>();
}
else {
    GenericClass<String> mygen = new GenericClass<String>();  
}
```

Suppose that I have multiple methods, and I want to use:

```
mygen.method1();
...
mygen.method100();
```

If I cannot use the same name of "mygen" for either Integer or String type, based on the user's input, then what is the benefit of having a generic type? I mean, then I have to repeat these 100 lines for another type.

Comment: Generics are for _compile-time_ type-safety.  Your example is the wrong place to use generics.

Comment: Instead of using generics, why don't you just use simple inheritance and let `mygen` have the type of the base class?

Comment: I don't know why you find it not suitable as a generics example. It is exactly what it could be resolved by generics! you have a class that have different methods. This class and its methods can accept any type of data, based on the user requirements.

Comment: Actually `mygen` scope is only in `if-block` then another local variable `mygen` in `else`

Comment: Indeed, your variables immediately go out of scope...

Comment: You are right about the scope of the variable. So, it simply means there is no way not to repeat those 100 lines?

Comment: Put them in a method?  `<T> void doStuff(GenericClass<T> mygen)`.  However, that won't achieve a great deal, due to type erasure.  Where exactly does the behaviour differ based on type?

Comment: you can think of methods as search, comparison, add, delete.. anything. the class is a list of Strings, or Integers or Doubles, ..

Comment: @Computer_guy: But `GenericClass<Integer>` and `GenericClass<String>` are actually *the same class*.  `method1()`, `method2()` do exactly the same thing in either case.  So either wrap it all in a method (as above), or declare `mygen` outside the `if` block as a `GenericClass<?>`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Thanks. I think your answer is the best one. However, I am not sure how to wrap it in a method (some functions needs a value to be passes. So type of that value is also unknown) Could you please add your answer as a code, so I can mark it as an answer?